# Node.JS Joi casts error for unknown object

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm running Node.JS and Joi (including express-joi-middleware), and are trying to either silently ignore unknown objects or strip them. However, whatever I do an error is returned.

```
const options = { wantResponse: false, stripUnknown: true };
app.post('/my-post', expressJoiMiddleware(testSchema, options), (req, res) => {
...
```

and

```
const options = { wantResponse: false, allowUnknown: true };
app.post('/my-post', expressJoiMiddleware(testSchema, options), (req, res) => {
...
```

Gives me:

```
{
    "error": [
        {
            "message": "\"test\" is not allowed",
            "path": "body.test",
            "type": "object.allowUnknown",
            "context": {
                "child": "test",
                "key": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work with:

```
const options = { wantResponse: false, joiOptions: { stripUnknown: true }};
```

Comment: `allowUnknown: true` prefering this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add Joi validation to a route, payload or parameter, it strictly checks for the properties. The `.required()` means that the property is required, however if the property is **not** mentioned in the schema, it takes it as a violation and throws that error.

For Joi to work properly, you need to define everything you **may** use. That's the definition of a schema - a definition of all the fields of a structure: required or not.

I had the same problem with `Hapi.js` and adding the property to the schema fixed it.

---

A simple example would be:

```
{
    user: Joi.string().required(),
    pass: Joi.string().required()
}
```

For this *route*, if you pass in **only** `user` or `pass`, it'll fail as the other is required as well. However, if you try to pass a `name`, it'll fail again with the error you're getting because Joi does not recognise that property. Consider it like a sanity check so that no "malignant" fields are passed on as a payload.

If you change the above schema to:

```
{
    ...
    name: Joi.string()
}
```

Joi will have no problem passing it through because then it'd know that `name` is something which you can expect.

Comment: But I thought the `stripUnknown: true` removed unknown parameters etc., and `allowUnknown: true` silently ignored unknown parameters?

Comment: As opposed to its name, `stripUnknown` does something a little different. As per [this](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/615) bug report, `stripUnknown` just removes the items which aren't valid in an array instead of removing keys from an object. The routing parameters are `keys` in an object as opposed to `items` in an array.

Comment: I see. Apparently though it worked with changing code to `const options = { wantResponse: false, joiOptions: { stripUnknown: true }};`

Comment: That is pretty interesting. :|

Comment: ...but guess `allowUnknown: true` is better, in my case at least.

Comment: Brilliant! Close the question then! :D